# Embedded Widget Yotpo bigcommerce

Tags: widget, embedded, bigcommerce

can somebody help me why my Embedded widget don't appear on my yotpo app? Im using bigcommerce platform. I already try uninstalling and installing it over and over but the results still same.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the built in reviews.
[image: Settings > Comments > Built-in]
Deselect the Product reviews checkbox then save.

To install Yotpo social reviews widget:

Log in to your Bigcommerce Admin page.

- Click Settings.
- Click Design in the Store Setup column.
- Click Edit HTML/CSS.
- Click ProductDetails.html under Other Template Files-Panels.
- Add the following code after the last line of the file.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  //<![CDATA[
  var div = document.createElement("div");
  div.setAttribute('class', 'yotpo yotpo-main-widget');
  div.setAttribute('data-product-id', "%%GLOBAL_ProductId%%");
  div.setAttribute('data-name', "%%GLOBAL_ProductName%%");
  div.setAttribute('data-url', document.URL);
  div.setAttribute('data-description', "");
  div.setAttribute('data-image-url', "%%GLOBAL_ThumbImageURL%%");
  if ($(".yotpo.placeholder").length) {
    $(".yotpo.placeholder").append(div);
  } else {
    $("#ProductDescription").append(div);
  }
  //]]>
  </script>
  ```

  [image: ProductDetails]
- Add the Yotpo JavaScript code below directly to HTMLHead.html.
- Go to Design > Edit HTML/CSS and find HTMLHead.html.
- Add the following code after the last line of the file, just above `</head>`.

  ```
  <script type="text/javascript">
  (function e() {
  var e = document.createElement("script");
  e.type = "text/javascript", e.async = true, e.src = "//staticw2.yotpo.com/YOUR-APP_KEY/widget.js";
  var t = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  t.parentNode.insertBefore(e, t)
  })();
  </script>
  ```

[image: HTMLHead]

Don't forget to replace YOUR-APP_KEY with your key.

Comment: What if I'm using the stencil design hence I have no access to /admin?